# R: igraph eccentricity seems not use weighed edge

Tags: r, igraph

I use igraph to compute the vertices eccentricity, the graph is weighted, and random generated as following

```
n <- 500
g <- sample_smallworld(1, n, 10, 0.05)
E(g)$weight <- (runif(1)+0.1)*10
is.weighed(g)
dia <- diameter(g)
dia
```

It is a small world network, with 500 vertices, and random weighted edges. Use `diameter` and 'is.weighted' to check it does be weighted. However, `eccentricity` does not use the weight, and generate the following result,

```
d_list <- eccentricity(g)
summary(d_list)
```

output as following,

> d_list <- eccentricity(g)
>   summary(d_list)
>       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
>     4.000   4.000   4.000   4.004   4.000   5.000

how to solve this problem?

now I use `max(distances(g))` to solve it, but I think it not an efficient and  elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think eccentricity give you the option but if I will not pronounce myself about the elegancy of the distances() method, from an efficiency point of view both algorithms will execute in `O(|V|^2*log(|V|))` (assuming `|E| = O(|V|)`) to compute the eccentricity of each node, if you run some test you get this:

```
f1 <- function(n) {
  g <- sample_smallworld(1, n, 10, 0.05)
  E(g)$weight <- (runif(n*10)+0.1)*10
  system.time(eccentricity(g))
}

f2 <- function(n) {
  g <- sample_smallworld(1, n, 10, 0.05)
  E(g)$weight <- (runif(n*10)+0.1)*10
  system.time(distances(g))
}


f3 <- function(n) {
  g <- sample_smallworld(1, n, 10, 0.05)
  tmp <- (runif(n*10)+0.1)*10
  system.time(eccentricity(g))
}

f4 <- function(n) {
  g <- sample_smallworld(1, n, 10, 0.05)
  tmp <- (runif(n*10)+0.1)*10
  system.time(distances(g))
}

t1 <- sapply((10:60)*50, function(x){f1(x)[3]})
t2 <- sapply((10:60)*50, function(x){f2(x)[3]})
t3 <- sapply((10:60)*50, function(x){f3(x)[3]})
t4 <- sapply((10:60)*50, function(x){f4(x)[3]})

d <- data.frame(x = (10:60)*50, t1, t2, t3, t4)


ggplot(d, aes(x = x))+
  geom_line(aes(y = t1, col = "'Weighted' eccentricity"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = t2, col = "Weighted distances"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = t3, col = "Unweighted eccentricity"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = t4, col = "Unweighted distances")) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Number of Nodes") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Time (s)")
```

[image: Unscaled time performance of the different algorithm]

As you can see they all have the same time asymptotic complexity, but in the unweighted case the use of BFS gives a better time constant. (To illustrate the asymptotic complexity, see the scaled graph below:)

[image: Scaled time performance]